# How to change default language of facebook login dialog in ionic?

Tags: facebook, typescript, ionic3

I am trying to implement login using fb in my ionic app. I am new to both ionic and facebook api.

My problem is when I login using facebook login I see the dialog for facebook login in a different language. as displayed in the image.

But, what I want is load this dialog in **English** by default. How to do it?

[image: facebook login screen].

here is my code for login in login.ts:

```
loginFb() {
    this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
      .then(res => {
        if(res.status === "connected") {
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
          this.getFbUserDetail(res.authResponse.userID);
        } else {
          this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
      })
      .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
  }

getFbUserDetail(userid) {
    this.fb.api("/"+userid+"/?fields=id,email,name,picture,gender",["public_profile"])
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.users = res;
        console.log('name',this.users.name);
        console.log('gender',this.users.gender);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
```

I have followed [this](https://www.djamware.com/post/59ad3a0c80aca768e4d2b135/login-with-ionic-3-and-cordova-native-facebook-connect-plugin) link to connecct facebook with ionic app.

Comment: Not entirely sure if this is possible. From facebook docs:  *"Dialog such as the Login Dialog render in the language that the person has picked as their native language on Facebook, even if it's different than the language you select."* Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization

Comment: @Ivaro18 Thanks for Info.

Comment: I haven't used the plugin myself so this answer is totally based on that link. Please keep in mind that I don't know if this is actually true for the plugin you're using.

Comment: @Ivaro18 No problem.